# Unexpected node/js function execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got simple function running in node, code below

```
        const check = arr => {
                        let res;
                        let x = arr.filter((el, i, self) => self.indexOf(el) == i).length;
                        let y = arr.length;
                        console.log('x,y: ', x, y);
                        x === y ? (res = true) : (res = false);
                        return res;
            };
```

For some reason the console.log in the example return 0,0 despite the arr input. When i comment out this line

```
x === y ? (res = true) : (res = false);
```

console.log shows proper values of x,y. Anybody knows whats wrong with this code? (I tried with "ifs" as well, same result.

Comment: `res = x === y;` is more succinct.

Comment: true, but yet cause same erros

Comment: What does the array look like?

Comment: what's funny, if I comment out "return res" console.logs shows correct values. Its as though return was somehow executing before everything else, causing misfunctioning?

Comment: Array is simply 14 elements with chars, function is meant to check if chars are unique.

Comment: I guess that you call this function with an empty array

Comment: I'm not, the point is when the return statement is commented out, console.logs shows correct values for x,y whilst when return is there, console.logs show 0,0

Comment: could you provide more info like the exact value of the array, and how you are executing the function?
because "It works on my machine"

Comment: if I run 
`console.log(check(["1", "f", "3", "s", "f"]));`
then I get
`x,y:  4 5
false`
on my console
and i think that is right. RIGHT?

Comment: thats the result i should get. For some reason sths wrong with return statements on my side

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the hustle. Just realized in the loop im using this function, first element was indeed empty array, deep apologies for the confusion